# Animations in programs using Gsap and pixiJS do not work

Tags: node.js, typescript, warnings, gsap, pixi.js

I am currently trying to create an animation by connecting Pixi.js and gsap. Specifically, it is an animation where white text appears and disappears on a black background. However, when I run it in the browser, the following warning appears and the animation does not execute.

```
Container {_events: Events, _eventsCount: 0, tempDisplayObjectParent: null, transform: _Transform, alpha: 1, …}
overrideMethod  @   react_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367
Show 44 more frames
```

Also, this warning is printed out approximately 3 times per second, so I assume that it is issued each time the timeLine to is executed. How can I get the animation to run? What is your solution? Here is the source code for this program

```
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { Application, ICanvas } from "pixi.js";
import firstView from "./firstview";
import { PixiPlugin } from "gsap/PixiPlugin";

type chairInfoType = {
  id: string;
  x: number;
  y: number;
  people: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
  };
};

export default function main(app: Application<ICanvas>, data: chairInfoType[]) {
  console.log("start!");
  gsap.registerPlugin(PixiPlugin);

  const tl = gsap.timeline();
  tl.add(firstView(app));

  tl.play();

  return 0;
}
```

```
import { gsap } from "gsap/all";
import {
  Application,
  Container,
  DisplayObject,
  ICanvas,
  Text,
  TextStyle,
} from "pixi.js";

export default function firstView(app: Application<ICanvas>) {
  const tl = gsap.timeline();

  const firstViewContainer = new Container();

  app.stage.addChild(firstViewContainer);

  setup(firstViewContainer);

  tl.to(firstViewContainer, { pixi: { alpha: 1 }, duration: 1 });
  tl.to(firstViewContainer, { pixi: { alpha: 0 }, duration: 1 });
  tl.to(firstViewContainer, { pixi: { alpha: 1 }, duration: 1 });
  return tl;
}

function setup(firstViewContainer: Container<DisplayObject>) {
  const logoCon = new Container();

  const kyouryokuMain = new Text(
    "鯖建",
    new TextStyle({
      fontFamily: [
        "游明朝",
        "YuMincho",
        "Hiragino Mincho ProN",
        "HGS明朝E",
        "ＭＳ Ｐ明朝",
        "ＭＳ 明朝",
        "serif",
      ],
      fontSize: 50,
      fill: "white",
      align: "center",
    })
  );
  const koyuryokuSab = new Text(
    "Server",
    new TextStyle({
      fontFamily: [
        "游ゴシック体",
        "YuGothic",
        "游ゴシック",
        "Yu Gothic",
        "ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3",
        "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro",
        "メイリオ",
        "Meiryo",
        "sans-serif",
      ],
      fontSize: 15,
      fill: "white",
      align: "center",
    })
  );
  kyouryokuMain.y = 25;
  koyuryokuSab.y = -8;

  kyouryokuMain.anchor.set(0.5);
  koyuryokuSab.anchor.set(0.5);

  logoCon.x = window.innerWidth / 2;
  logoCon.y = window.innerHeight / 2;

  logoCon.addChild(koyuryokuSab);
  logoCon.addChild(kyouryokuMain);
  firstViewContainer.addChild(logoCon);
}
```